# JavaScript documentation issue when having functions with the same name

Tags: javascript, code-documentation

I am working on a JavaScript library and trying to keep it well documented.
I am structuring it in a way that I will end-up with functions for different objects, but the same name, and when adding documentation to it, it always picks up the signature for the first function and not the correct one for that object.
I created a simple example for that:

`

```
var MyLibrary = MyLibrary || {};

MyLibrary = {
    User: function (T) {
        /**
         * This is my User.function1
         */
        this.function1 = function () {
            return "1";
        };
        /**
         * asdsa
         * @returns 
         */
        this.function2 = function () {
            return "2";
        };
    },
    Controls: function (T) {
        /**
       * This is my Controls.function1
       */
        this.function1 = function () {
            return "1";
        };
        /**
         * This is my Controls.function2
         */
        this.function2 = function () {
            return "2";
        };
    }
};
```

`
When using the function **MyLibrary.Controls.function1**, the function name for **MyLibrary.User.function1** is showing.

[image]

Am I missing something or is this because of the way I am structuring my code? any tips?

thanks

Comment: It's odd that `MyLibrary.Controls.function1` is showing you anything at all, since `MyLibrary.Controls` doesn't have a `function1`. (The object that would be returned by `new MyLibrary.Controls` has a `function1`, but the function `MyLibrary.Controls` doesn't.)

Comment: Is there a particular reason this needs to be organized in this way? There are three things about it that are odd here in 2022 (IMHO): 1. It's using only ES5 features. ES2015 (actually ES2019/20 or so) is universally supported in non-obsolete environments, and for obsolete environments there are tools that can compile modern code to near-equivalent ES5. 2. It's creating instance functions rather than prototype functions, but the `User` and `Control` functions seem to be designed to be constructor functions. Sometimes you need to do that, but is that really the case? 3. It's not using modules.

Comment: The above is a genuine question, not snark. :-) It's just the simplest answer to your queston is: Write modern code, and the IDE will understand it. It's not an excuse for the IDE getting it wrong (and it clearly is, at least in my case with VS Code, in two ways -- showing `function1` on `MyLibrary.Controls` when it doesn't have one, and showing the wrong docs -- as you said -- for `new MyLibrary.Controls().function1`.

Comment: Finally: You seem to be using VS Code. Is that true?

Comment: Yes I am using VS Code (forgot to mention that).

Comment: Fair point, I need to initiate my controls object first, but even when doing below, I get the same result:

var myControl = new MyLibrary.Controls("my id");
myControl.function1();

I am inheriting an existing library and extending it, so wanted to keep the same structure. But I am more than happy to hear a more modern approach if you can share how it would look like.

thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why VS Code gets those wrong, other than that it appears to be keying off just the function names.

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877152/javascript-documentation-issue-when-having-functions-with-the-same-name/74877303#comment132140689_74877152) you said you'd be open to solving the problem with a more modern structure, so here's what I'd probably do:

```
export class User {
    constructor(t) {
        // ...do something with `t`...
    }

    /**
     * This is my User.function1
     */
    function1() {
        return "1";
    }

    /**
     * asdsa
     * @returns
     */
    function2() {
        return "2";
    }
}

export class Controls {
    constructor(t) {
        // ...do something with `t`...
    }

    /**
     * This is my Controls.function1
     */
    function1() {
        return "1";
    }

    /**
     * This is my Controls.function2
     */
    function2() {
        return "2";
    }
}
```

That:

1. Uses [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax to create the constructor functions
2. Shares the methods across instances of classes by putting them on the prototype
3. Exports the classes (constructor functions) via [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

If you need to have private information that you previously were going to close over in the constructor, you might consider [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields) which your constructor and methods can use, but which no other code can see.

Here's how you'd use those from another module:

```
import { Controls } from "./MyLibrary.js";

let controls = new Controls("arg");
console.log(controls.function1()); // <== Has the right documentation
```

Or if you like, you can do a module namespace import, which results in an object with properties for each named export:

```
import * as MyLibrary from "./MyLibrary.js";

let controls = new MyLibrary.Controls("arg");
console.log(controls.function1()); // <== Has the right documentation
```

More information can be found in the MDN links above, and in my recent(ish) book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev) which covers `class` syntax (Chapter 4), modern modules (Chapter 13), and private fields (Chapter 18).